# ExtJS - How do I nest a Ext.Component

Tags: html, extjs, nested

I'm trying to nest one `Ext.Component` into another `Ext.Component`:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
   cls: 'my-thing',
   autoEl: {
      tag: 'div',
      style: 'display: block;'
   },
   id: 'myId',
   type: 'image',
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   items: [
      {
         xtype: 'component',
         autoEl: {
            tag: 'div',
            style: 'display: block;'
         },
         id: 'myOtherID',
      },
  ]
});
```

This doesn't work, the nested `div` doesn't render.

I just need 2 nested `div` with different styles.

Comment: Try to use renderTpl

Comment: Hi @ArthurRubens I tried adding the `renderTpl` as you suggested but the inner content still doesn't render. Can you please provide code showing how it works?

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Title.js.html